# IsCustomResponse is always returning false in Adapter-based authentication

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am following the tutorial on implementing Adapter-based authentication on https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/

`isCustomReponse` method is always returning false because "authRequired" is not in the response. Please help me if i am doing anything wrong.

Adapter Code

```
function onAuthRequired(headers, errorMessage){
    errorMessage = errorMessage ? errorMessage : null;

    return {
        authRequired: true,
        errorMessage: errorMessage
    };
}

function submitAuthentication(username, password){
  // if (username==="user" && password === "user"){

    var userIdentity = {
        userId: username,
        displayName: username,
        attributes: {
          foo: "bar"
        }
    };

    WL.Server.setActiveUser("SingleStepAuthRealm", userIdentity);

    return {
      authRequired: false
    };
  // }

  // return onAuthRequired(null, "Invalid login credentials");
}


function onLogout(){
    WL.Logger.debug("Logged out");
}
```

AuthenticationConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:loginConfiguration xmlns:tns="http://www.worklight.com/auth/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

        <!-- Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
             5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2006, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
             US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
             disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp. -->  

     <staticResources>
     <!--  
            <resource id="logUploadServlet" securityTest="LogUploadServlet">
            <urlPatterns>/apps/services/loguploader*</urlPatterns>
        </resource>
        -->
        <resource id="subscribeServlet" securityTest="SubscribeServlet">
            <urlPatterns>/subscribeSMS*;/receiveSMS*;/ussd*</urlPatterns>
        </resource>

    </staticResources> 


     <securityTests>

        <customSecurityTest name="SubscribeServlet">
            <test realm="SubscribeServlet" isInternalUserID="true"/>
        </customSecurityTest>   

        <customSecurityTest name="SingleStepAuthAdapter-securityTest">
            <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="SingleStepAuthRealm"/>
        </customSecurityTest>



    </securityTests> 

    <realms>

    <realm loginModule="AuthLoginModule" name="SingleStepAuthRealm">
            <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="login-function" value="SingleStepAuthAdapter.onAuthRequired"/>
            <parameter name="logout-function" value="SingleStepAuthAdapter.onLogout"/>
        </realm>
        <realm name="SampleAppRealm" loginModule="StrongDummy">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
        </realm>

        <realm name="SubscribeServlet" loginModule="rejectAll">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator</className>          
        </realm>

    </realms>

    <loginModules>
        <loginModule name="AuthLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>
        <loginModule name="StrongDummy" expirationInSeconds="-1">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <loginModule name="requireLogin" expirationInSeconds="-1">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.SingleIdentityLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <loginModule name="rejectAll">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.RejectingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

    </loginModules>

</tns:loginConfiguration>
```

Android Code

```
public void IBMPushNotification() {

  try {
    client.registerChallengeHandler(newLoginChallengeHandler(realm,"test"));
    client.connect(new MyConnectionListener());
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Login Challenge Handler

```
private LoginChallengeHandler challengeHandler;
private String realm = "SingleStepAuthRealm";


public class LoginChallengeHandler extends ChallengeHandler{

  private String userName;

    public LoginChallengeHandler(String realm,String user) {
      super(realm);
      userName = user;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCustomResponse(WLResponse wlResponse) {
      try {
        if(wlResponse!= null && wlResponse.getResponseJSON()!=null &&
            wlResponse.getResponseJSON().isNull("authRequired") != true &&
            wlResponse.getResponseJSON().getBoolean("authRequired") == true){

          return true;
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleChallenge(WLResponse wlResponse) {
      submitLogin(userName,"dummy");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(WLResponse wlResponse) {

      if(isCustomResponse(wlResponse)) {
        handleChallenge(wlResponse);
      } else {
        submitSuccess(wlResponse);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(WLFailResponse wlFailResponse) {    
    }

    public void submitLogin(String userName, String password){
      Object[] parameters = new Object[]{userName, password};
      WLProcedureInvocationData invocationData = new WLProcedureInvocationData("SingleStepAuthAdapter", "submitAuthentication");
      invocationData.setParameters(parameters);
      WLRequestOptions options = new WLRequestOptions();
      options.setTimeout(30000);
      submitAdapterAuthentication(invocationData, options);

    }
  }
```

Comment: have you taken a look at the native android sample for adapter-based authentication? https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/adapter-based-authentication-native-android-applications/

Comment: yes i did i followed the same thing, did i do any thing wrong in the posted code?

Comment: Does the sample as-is work for you? Before your changes?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your client code a procedure invocation. I see however a connect? Are you trying to protect the entire application? Make sure you added the security test in the application descriptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal for the Challenge Handler to be called many times with authRequired not being set - these are just normal server responses when authentication is not required. That authRequired payload will only be present if you have triggered the authentication process by accessing a protected resource, which in turn will cause the security subsystem to invoke the adapter onAuthRequired method.

I suggest adding a trace statement to your onAuthRequired method, this will show you when that is happening.

As Nathan H has said the likeliest causes here is that you are not accessing a protected resource because you have not applied your security test to an adapter procedure or the application as a whole. In the example your are working from there is a getSecretData() procedure that is so protected.

Comment: Nice explanation.. "That authRequired payload will only be present if you have triggered the authentication process by accessing a protected resource" I didn't saw this statement in IBM documentation .
I was thinking once i called registered  the challenge handler mobile first will automatically call the function present in the login module and send the payload with authrequired..
thank you very much..